# Postgres Combine Rows in into one array with Conditional Group Subquery

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, multidimensional-array

```
    CREATE TABLE "Logs"(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    product_id bigint,
    product_price numeric,
    product_store text
    last_updated timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
    );

INSERT into "Logs" VALUES(2095, 13, 249.99, 'BestBuy.com', '2023-04-08 00:20:12.199251+00');
INSERT into "Logs" VALUES(2096, 13, 249.99, 'Target.com', '2023-04-08 00:20:12.199251+00');
```

Query

```
SELECT json_object(array_agg(product_store), array_agg(json::text))as price_log FROM (
SELECT product_store, array_agg(array["Logs".product_price::text, "Logs".last_updated::text]) as json
                     FROM "Logs"
                     WHERE "Logs".product_id = 13
                     GROUP BY "Logs".product_store
) as price_log
```

Output

```
{
   "BestBuy.com":"{{24.99,\"2023-04-08 00:20:13.756603+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 22:57:56.003837+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-15 02:42:55.190658+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-15 16:57:55.045572+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-15 18:42:53.294265+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 02:57:51.220209+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 03:12:50.504241+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 05:57:50.356346+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 07:27:52.21909+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-16 00:42:52.578908+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-16 19:12:55.789055+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-25 00:57:55.631403+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 00:57:51.861773+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 02:27:54.083473+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-08 14:57:51.008387+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-18 11:57:54.997804+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-18 05:42:55.248361+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-18 12:12:54.926158+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-28 21:43:07.330042+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-25 23:12:58.103744+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-28 21:58:06.652304+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-20 06:42:55.641028+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-21 23:57:57.777371+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-20 15:12:56.185695+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-21 21:27:58.06414+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-22 04:27:58.140495+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-28 23:28:07.284809+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 00:58:06.053093+00\"},{24.99,\"2023-04-09 17:12:52.552401+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-22 01:27:58.035003+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-26 07:57:57.272001+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-22 00:27:56.772623+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-21 05:57:57.145709+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 03:28:06.034023+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-10 05:12:52.093764+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-21 21:57:59.336833+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-21 22:27:58.280576+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-28 21:28:05.418201+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-11 21:27:53.44626+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-22 15:27:56.237947+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-23 20:27:57.577541+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-13 13:57:52.456967+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 01:27:55.291552+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 21:27:58.342033+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 21:57:57.407943+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 06:43:06.139272+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 08:13:04.733555+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 13:13:06.21473+00\"},{34.99,\"2023-04-29 18:28:04.24191+00\"},{19.99,\"2023-04-30 05:43:02.277314+00\"},{19.99,\"2023-05-03 21:43:03.169792+00\"},{19.99,\"2023-05-08 20:13:07.710327+00\"},{19.99,\"2023-05-08 21:58:07.183089+00\"},{19.99,\"2023-05-10 07:13:07.101684+00\"}}",
   "Target.com":"{{39.99,\"2023-04-11 00:53:57.742973+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 03:15:01.237546+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-13 23:45:03.201827+00\"},{39.99,\"2023-04-14 00:00:01.635091+00\"},{33.99,\"2023-05-03 02:11:36.148637+00\"},{33.99,\"2023-05-03 02:17:06.085251+00\"}}"
}
```

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, I am trying to combine the rows of "Logs" that are associated with a Product ID, since this is being used in a Subquery I need this query to be in an array since there are times where there are more than one result, like above.

My desired result is:

```
    {
    "BestBuy.com": {
        "data": [
            [24.99, "2023-04-08 00:20:13.756603+00"],
            [24.99, "2023-04-08 00:20:13.756603+00"]
        ]
    },
    "Target.com": {
        "data": [
            [24.99, "2023-04-08 00:20:13.756603+00"],
            [24.99, "2023-04-08 00:20:13.756603+00"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you also provide sample data as `insert` statements with the table definition?

Comment: @Albina sorry about that, I've made the edits!

Comment: Please check your desired json, it is not valid.

Comment: @Albina Sorry again, please check now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- final JSON
with tmp as (
    select json_build_object(product_store, json_build_object('Data', json_agg(t.a))) json_row from (
      select
        product_store, json_build_array(product_price,last_updated) a
        from "Logs" 
    ) t
    group by product_store)
select json_object_agg(key, value) as result
from   tmp, json_each(json_row);
```

**Details:**

1. Inner query constructs an array from 2 columns per row using function
   `json_build_array(product_price, last_updated)`
2. Function `json_agg` concatenates all the arrays into one array grouping by `product_store`.
3. The `json_build_object` function builds the output json.
4. Finally, `json_object_agg` with `json_each` sort of concatenate `json_row`s into the final output.

**Output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 { "BestBuy.com" : {"Data" : [[249.99, "2023-04-08T00:20:12.199251+00:00"], [249.99, "2023-04-09T00:20:12.199251+00:00"], [249.99, "2023-04-10T00:20:12.199251+00:00"]]}, "Target.com" : {"Data" : [[249.99, "2023-04-08T00:20:12.199251+00:00"], [249.99, "2023-04-11T00:20:12.199251+00:00"], [249.99, "2023-04-12T00:20:12.199251+00:00"]]} }
(1 row)
```

See [**dbfiddle link**](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3z87hptz9).

Comment: Since I am using this in a subquery, I can't have two separate rows, anyway to combine them into one? Where the output is similar to the desired result?

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez I've updated my answer. By the way, I am here trying to help you and you could be nicer in your responses.

Comment: I apologize, that was not my intent. I appreciate the help!